# How to use JavaScript to test a HTML div on content from an external database?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a `html` letter. Each letter may or may not have conditions attached to it. Those conditions are stored in an `external sql database`.

What if a `html div` contained database field such as:-

```
<div id="Conditions">
    <p>dbfield(var)</p>
</div>
```

What I need to do is test the resultant data rather than the actual `div` itself. See my last attempt:-

```
<div id="Conditions">
    <p>dbfield(conditions)</p>
</div>

<div id="NoConditions">
    <p>No specific conditions apply</p>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
<!-- 
    if (document.getElementById("Conditions").innerHTML.length == 0){
        document.getElementById("Conditions").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("NoConditions").style.display = "inline";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("NoConditions").style.display = "inline";   
        document.getElementById("Conditions").style.display = "none";   
    }
//-->
</script>
```

In a nutshell, my dilemma is I want to test whether a result is returned from the database or not.

I know this is a strange one but this is a `third party db` that I only have read access to inside a `web based interface` that creates the `html` form letters. However the prebuilt system has very limited functionality (can't use if's or then's) hence why I am using `javascript` to get around those limitations.

I'm assuming it is doing something tricky with the type of data in the `div` as I have tried NULL tests, "" tests, `innerHTML` tests, using a `i++ counter`, `children` tests, `haschildnode()` tests. So far it has resisted all my interrogations.

Any assistance would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What does it look like inside `Conditions` when you inspect element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditions that you have put in your script is wrong. You have displayed the `NoConditions div` as inline in both `if` and `else` sections. Secondly, the `length` of `innerHTML` of `Conditions div` will always be greater than 0 since it has a `p` inside it everytime. So get the `innerHTML` of the `p` tag instead. Below is the snippet for the same. I hope this resolves your query.

```js
var pText = document.getElementById("Conditions").getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML;
if (pText.length == 0){
        document.getElementById("Conditions").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("NoConditions").style.display = "inline";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("Conditions").style.display = "inline";   
        document.getElementById("NoConditions").style.display = "none";   
    }
```

```html
<div id="Conditions">
    <p>Conditions</p>
</div>

<div id="NoConditions">
    <p>No specific conditions apply</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the super quick answer. Works perfectly now. The style.display "inline" and "none" problem was my error after editing the script too many times whilst actually trying to do my real job :-P